# Wordpress as cms for different page content per country

Tags: php, wordpress

**Which plugin to use?**

I use wordpress as a CMS and was wondering which plugin I could use make 1 page with dynamic content for different selected country/per domain/URL?

(I would like to have many versions of the same site where, some pages have common page content while other pages have different page content)

Comment: To better understand, you wish to refine which posts show on the site based on where the visitor is from?  So a visitor from the US would see posts 1, 2,3,4 while someone from say, Argentina would see 3,4,5,6?

Comment: This is really more a usage question instead of a programming question.  You might try asking on SuperUser or the new Web Apps Stack Exchange site: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... and now there's also wordpress.stackexchange.com (better than webapps imho for a question like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/

Answer (score 0):

Try qTranslate
http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/

used it successfully to provide translations (with different content) on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Agree strongly with the previous poster who suggested WPML (WordPress Multilingual) plugin.

It's a very sophisticated extension to WordPress and provides a number of different ways of implementing multilingual capabilities. It is easy to set-up but you do need to think carefully about how you configure it.

There isn't a problem with its configuration procedures, but do read through all the settings and think about the implications of the different options.