# Recommended way to localize a WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog in English (admin and content). Now I need a Spanish version of that same blog (admin English, content Spanish).

Should I replicate the blog and then translate its content (images, posts, etc.)? Or is there a plug-in I could use for this scenario? I appreciate your advice.

Comment: See previous question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420947/wordpress-as-cms-for-different-page-content-per-country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-network duplicate? [WordPress StackExchange discussion on the subject.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/best-practices-for-localizing-wordpress-content)